# Track how long a user has watched a video android exoplayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

i want to add this function in my application, How long did the user watch the video in Exo Player? can anyone tell me this code if is it possible. please solve out this problem.

Answer (score 4):

From ExoPlayer 2.11 you can use `PlaybackStatsListener`.

To use PlaybackStatsListener, register an instance with the player by calling `player.addAnalyticsListener(playbackStatsListener)`.

Can use `playbackStatsListener.playbackStats.totalPlayTimeMs` to get total played duration.

Answer (score 2):

**Few notes**

Yes it possible, videos' runtime played in ExoPlayer can be easily tracked down.

**What you can do**

For this example, I used kotlin and **ExoPlayer v2.9.3**

```
mPlayer.addListener(object : IPlayerEventListener {
          override fun onPlayerStateChanged(playWhenReady: Boolean, playbackState: Int) {
               super.onPlayerStateChanged(playWhenReady, playbackState)
               if (playbackState == Player.STATE_READY) {
                    // Apply some logic here whenever you want to get the duration
                    var durationMillis = mPlayer.getDuration()

                    // Apply some logic here to send out the data to your servers (whether after video paused, resumed, stopped, your choice)
                    // Example (Assuming you use MVVM + RxJava + Retrofit, this is a common way to do network call)
                    viewModel.uploadPlaybackDetails(userId = 21, videoId = 18, playbackTime = durationMillis)
               }
          }

          override fun onPlayerError(error: ExoPlaybackException?) {
               super.onPlayerError(error)
               // Handle error here
          }
     })
```

Best to get the duration is listening to the ExoPlayer's state changed, especially when it is ready, otherwise if you do this

```
mPlayer.prepare()

// For example you attempted to get the duration immediately
mPlayer.getDuration()
```

You will see logs with `UNKNOWN_TIME` error.

**References**

- https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer

Comment: sir if i send you my application full source code do you add this feature to my application???? please help sir am newbie.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is seeing this while working with Xamarin.

For Xamarin.Android create a new class and inherit from `IPlayerEventListener` since we can't "new" up an interface.

```
public class CustomExoListener : Java.Lang.Object, IPlayerEventListener
    {
        PlayerView _player;
        public CustomExoListener(PlayerView player)
        {       
            _player = player;     
        }
        public void OnLoadingChanged(bool isLoading) { }
        public void OnPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) { }
        public void OnPlayerStateChanged(bool playWhenReady, int playbackState) 
        {
            if (playbackState != PlaybackState.PlaybackPositionUnknown)
            {
                var duration = _player.Player.Duration;
                var position = _player.Player.CurrentPosition;
                var percentageWatched = (100 * position / duration);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Player State: {playbackState} duration: {duration} position: {position} Watched: {percentageWatched}%");
            }
        }
        public void OnPositionDiscontinuity(int reason) { }
        public void OnSeekProcessed() { }
        public void OnIsPlayingChanged(bool isPlaying) { }
        public void OnTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, int reason) { }
        public void OnTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) { }
    }
```

Then allocate to the player

```
var exoPlayerView = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(ApplicationContext).Build();
var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(mediaUrl);

IHttpDataSourceFactory httpDataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(Util.GetUserAgent(ApplicationContext, "ChangeToYourAppName"));
IMediaSource mediaSource = new HlsMediaSource.Factory(httpDataSourceFactory).CreateMediaSource(uri);

// Prepare the player with the source.
exoPlayerView.Prepare(mediaSource);
exoPlayerView.AddListener(new CustomExoListener());
```

And do whatever you need to do in the events from the new class inheriting from `IPlayerEventListener`